# Application crashing while launch iOS 15 or later devices

Tags: ios, ios15, xcode13

Can somebody please help me understand the issue of crash when it is launching:

When iOS prewarms (This is the new IOS 15 feature ) the app after some time and the user launches the app then it is getting crash.

Prewarming Apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app/about_the_app_launch_sequence#3894431

```
    Incident Identifier: B53F9964-33AC-4E23-B27A-F49BA687B109
CrashReporter Key:   a63a0db0a7a8ed7f3ca168880d608ec27a2c598e
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             KP9 [706]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7598A335-DB75-4843-934E-48C0B65AAA35/KP9.app/KP9
Identifier:          com.test.kk
Version:             2021.3.2 (202112290503)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.test.kk [635]
 
Date/Time:           2022-01-09 22:16:49.0892 +0530
Launch Time:         2022-01-09 16:15:37.0788 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.2 (19C56)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    6.01.01
Report Version:      104
 
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-create watchdog transgression: application<com.test.kk>:706 exhausted CPU time allowance of 4.99 seconds
ProcessVisibility: Foreground
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: scene-create
WatchdogVisibility: Foreground
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.100 (user 7.100, system 0.000), 64% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.453, 49% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
 
Triggered by Thread:  0
 
Kernel Triage:
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
VM - Compressor failed a blocking pager_get
 
 
Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec1134 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                               0x183d3fb60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                               0x183d43c48 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184
4   CoreFoundation                               0x183d56e1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                                        0x1854903cc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                                        0x1854cec3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   KP9                                       0x1030b5988 0x102dd4000 + 3021192
8   UIKitCore                                            0x186586888 -[UIApplication(StateRestoration) _restoreApplicationPreservationStateWithSessionIdentifier:beginHandler:completionHandler:] + 6136
9   UIKitCore                                            0x18662f138 -[UIApplication(StateRestoration) _doRestorationIfNecessary] + 244
10  UIKitCore                                          0x1863ab3fc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 276
11  UIKitCore                                          0x186581c7c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3456
12  UIKitCore                                          0x18656aed4 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1216
13  UIKitCore                                          0x1863d7944 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 148
14  UIKitCore                                          0x18623b9c4 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 96
15  UIKitCore                                          0x18635fbe0 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 196
16  UIKitCore                                          0x1864762c4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 240
17  UIKitCore                                          0x1866a1f60 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 732
18  UIKitCore                                          0x186631ba0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 336
19  UIKitCore                                          0x18623c8ac __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 188
20  UIKitCore                                          0x1862f8c4c +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 812
21  UIKitCore                                          0x18623e63c _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 248
22  UIKitCore                                          0x186323ebc -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 356
23  UIKitCore                                          0x18677edb8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.576 + 772
24  UIKitCore                                          0x18626c910 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 248
25  UIKitCore                                          0x1862ae770 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 264
26  UIKitCore                                          0x1863dc4dc -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 548
27  UIKitCore                                          0x1863222d8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
28  FrontBoardServices                        0x19499baac -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 412
29  FrontBoardServices                        0x1949be0cc __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.180 + 100
30  FrontBoardServices                        0x19497e0f0 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
31  FrontBoardServices                        0x19497f4f8 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 312
32  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a971a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a39ad0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 220
34  FrontBoardServices                        0x19497f7d0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
35  FrontBoardServices                        0x19497ecdc -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 176
36  FrontBoardServices                        0x194982e44 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 24
37  CoreFoundation                              0x183deb2b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
38  CoreFoundation                              0x183dfb2d8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
39  CoreFoundation                              0x183d3e678 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
40  CoreFoundation                              0x183d43aa8 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
41  CoreFoundation                              0x183d56e1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
42  GraphicsServices                             0x1a40d99a0 GSEventRunModal + 160
43  UIKitCore                                          0x18658a600 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
44  UIKitCore                                          0x18631fb08 UIApplicationMain + 2028
45  KP9                                     0x1030af288 0x102dd4000 + 2994824
46  dyld                                    0x103bcc250 start + 444
 
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 2 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 2:
0   libcorecrypto.dylib                           0x1a7c5f568 ccsha512_final + 264
1   libcorecrypto.dylib                           0x1a7c5f4d4 ccsha512_final + 116
2   libcorecrypto.dylib                           0x1a7c94af0 F + 292
3   libcorecrypto.dylib                           0x1a7c94950 ccpbkdf2_hmac + 356
4   libcommonCrypto.dylib                0x1de1dc2c8 CCKeyDerivationPBKDF + 144
5   SQLCipher                                          0x103f9f9e4 sqlcipher_cc_kdf + 188
6   SQLCipher                                          0x103f9ec68 sqlcipher_cipher_ctx_key_derive + 532
7   SQLCipher                                          0x103f9e988 sqlcipher_codec_key_derive + 36
8   SQLCipher                                          0x103fb1950 sqlite3Codec + 56
9   SQLCipher                                          0x103fb915c readDbPage + 252
10  SQLCipher                                         0x103fb8c10 getPageNormal + 432
11  SQLCipher                                         0x103fbc120 btreeGetPage + 48
12  SQLCipher                                         0x103f9c5e0 sqlite3BtreeBeginTrans + 560
13  SQLCipher                                         0x103fd1a28 sqlite3InitOne + 552
14  SQLCipher                                         0x103fafffc sqlite3Init + 76
15  SQLCipher                                         0x103fdd980 sqlite3ReadSchema + 48
16  SQLCipher                                         0x103fa9b64 sqlite3LocateTable + 64
17  SQLCipher                                         0x104000d04 selectExpander + 1040
18  SQLCipher                                         0x103ff9f80 sqlite3WalkSelect + 52
19  SQLCipher                                         0x1040004d8 sqlite3SelectPrep + 132
20  SQLCipher                                         0x103fe6fb8 sqlite3Select + 208
21  SQLCipher                                         0x103fdf7e0 yy_reduce + 2500
22  SQLCipher                                         0x103fac6dc sqlite3RunParser + 604
23  SQLCipher                                         0x103fda120 sqlite3Prepare + 280
24  SQLCipher                                         0x103fab9dc sqlite3LockAndPrepare + 152
25  KP9                                     0x102df22d4 0x102dd4000 + 123604
26  KP9                                     0x102df258c 0x102dd4000 + 124300
27  KP9                                     0x102df2ec8 0x102dd4000 + 126664
28  KP9                                     0x102df1a7c 0x102dd4000 + 121468
29  KP9                                     0x102df7ea4 0x102dd4000 + 147108
30  KP9                                     0x102dfe768 0x102dd4000 + 173928
31  KP9                                     0x102df3e6c 0x102dd4000 + 130668
32  KP9                                     0x102df3ad0 0x102dd4000 + 129744
33  KP9                                     0x102f5cf9c 0x102dd4000 + 1609628
34  KP9                                     0x102fc544c 0x102dd4000 + 2036812
35  KP9                                     0x102fc504c 0x102dd4000 + 2035788
36  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a961a4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
37  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a971a8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
38  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a391fc _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 728
39  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a4643c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 340
40  libdispatch.dylib                              0x183a46c38 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 172
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1de36ee48 _pthread_wqthread + 224
42  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1de36e9f0 start_wqthread + 8
 
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec1134 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                               0x183d3fb60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                               0x183d43c48 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184
4   CoreFoundation                               0x183d56e1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   Foundation                                        0x1854903cc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                                        0x1854cec3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                                            0x186508348 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 512
8   Foundation                                        0x1854dc8ac __NSThread__start__ + 792
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de3703a4 _pthread_start + 116
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x1de36e9fc thread_start + 8
 
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 9 name:  com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec1134 mach_msg + 72
2   FirebaseCrashlytics                          0x1040eb884 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 104
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de3703a4 _pthread_start + 116
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9fc thread_start + 8
 
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9e8 start_wqthread + 0
 
Thread 11 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec0b10 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                    0x1bdec1134 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                               0x183d3fb60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 368
3   CoreFoundation                               0x183d43c48 __CFRunLoopRun + 1184
4   CoreFoundation                               0x183d56e1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
5   CFNetwork                                         0x18475bc88 0x18450f000 + 2411656
6   Foundation                                        0x1854dc8ac __NSThread__start__ + 792
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de3703a4 _pthread_start + 116
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1de36e9fc thread_start + 8
 
 
Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x0000000007000806   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000c00
    x4: 0x0000000000002803   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000281cc8340
    x8: 0x00000000fffffbbf   x9: 0x0000000007000906  x10: 0x893439334442004e  x11: 0x000000b2f280f58a
   x12: 0x00000000016e3600  x13: 0x000000000039bd23  x14: 0x0000010000000102  x15: 0x0000000000000001
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x0000000000000100  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000000ffffffff  x21: 0x0000000000002803  x22: 0x0000000000000c00  x23: 0x000000016d0280d0
   x24: 0x0000000007000806  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000007000806  x27: 0x0000000000002803
   x28: 0x0000000000002803   fp: 0x000000016d027f50   lr: 0x00000001bdec1134
    sp: 0x000000016d027f00   pc: 0x00000001bdec0b10 cpsr: 0x60000000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
 
Binary Images:
       0x1bdec0000 -        0x1bdef1fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <8f5f208de1bd3eb2994023b6d21843c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x183d39000 -        0x184173fff CoreFoundation arm64  <7a0c7b81a5b636a6b41cc7c790076454> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x185479000 -        0x185759fff Foundation arm64  <534d37b52b793993ab18822606b22abf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x102dd4000 -        0x1036ebfff KP9 arm64  <87a5e3db6b5d3f4f87ea42e30a50d814> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7598A335-DB75-4843-934E-48C0B65AAA35/KP9.app/KP9
       0x18609e000 -        0x18782dfff UIKitCore arm64  <d8869deee23832848c9a623313659320> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x194975000 -        0x194a13fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <21a2ad94245d3ba084bba0895e710331> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x183a33000 -        0x183ab5fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <a994086b41023d758ac5d3af5de2616d> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1a40d8000 -        0x1a40e0fff GraphicsServices arm64  <c88c86b0cde236239477bcd5d3965825> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x103bb4000 -        0x103c07fff dyld arm64  <0b12aec1caef38ad8fb73cab3da30489> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1de36a000 -        0x1de37dfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <263a2eadc4f33ef5bc4b7a61e6698c8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1a7c55000 -        0x1a7cccfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <913aec2c4e953ac89ec8e3354c4919c1> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
       0x1de1d3000 -        0x1de1dffff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <85e3107272293aecaff28bc0eb8d3266> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
       0x103f94000 -        0x104073fff SQLCipher arm64  <fff1c8a664e339a4b9aa9a80ba8836c7> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7598A335-DB75-4843-934E-48C0B65AAA35/KP9.app/Frameworks/SQLCipher.framework/SQLCipher
       0x1040d4000 -        0x10410ffff FirebaseCrashlytics arm64  <929f2f341b383885ab26364c8fee25d3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7598A335-DB75-4843-934E-48C0B65AAA35/KP9.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
       0x18450f000 -        0x1849a5fff CFNetwork arm64  <9ec6c90340d733f1bf3a06f57c3a4c15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
 
EOF
```

Comment: Well, the error message tells you what the problem is. You are taking way too long to launch so the WatchDog is killing you. During launch you need to do _nothing_. Get out of the way and permit launch to finish!

Answer (score 1):

In iOS there is something called the app WatchDog. In order to make sure that iOS doesn’t crash or become unresponsive it will kill any apps that are taking too long to respond.

This mostly happens if an app takes too long to launch. If you’re doing too much in the start up of the app this can happen.

It can be recognised by the funny error code of `0x8BADF00D`. Read aloud as “ate bad food”  .

In order to stop this you need to cut down what you are doing during the start up of your app. There are several WWDC talks about how you can do this. Plus several blogs that show methods to use also.

Comment: Hi @Fogmeister, this dubdub talk brought me here regarding 0x8BADF00D. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/414.

Comment: @EdgardoAgno hey!  how's it going?